# How to get number of user repositories using GitHub api?

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I'm trying to get number of repositories of user, without getting all repos using api.github.com/users/userName/repos. Is there any solution to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data at `https://api.github.com/users/userName` includes the key `public_repos` that denotes the number of public repositories for the given user

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do like this

> **Note**: in this example i'm using javascript

```js
fetch("https://api.github.com/users/YOUR_USERNAME")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => console.log(data.public_repos));
```